# How to delete all columns in matrix containing zeros in some rows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix whose size is `4x16` and I need to remove all columns which have the value of first row is zero. For example: here is the matrix example :

`X = [1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0.4 0 0; 0 0 0 0.8; 0.5 0 0 0];`

The 2D matrix (X) looks like this:

```
      1   0   0   0
      0   1   0   0
      0  0.4  0   0
      0   0   0  0.8
     0.5  0   0   0
```

So what I need is just `X = [1 0 0 0;0.5 0 0 0 ]` because the first row of these columns are different of Zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just exclude that row numbers:

```
X = X(X(:,1) ~= 0, :);
```

`X(:,1) ~= 0` is a boolean vector for the first column which is true if the value of the element would not be `0`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response ..I see you compare the whole column to 0, so if the column is not zeros, we keep. Unless,  we'll remove it.  But what I need is to only compare the first row of every column to zero and delete those columns whose first rows equals 0.

Comment: @Gze this is exactly what is done here. You said "I see you compare the whole column to 0" -> this is wrong, matlab always perform an element by element comparison.